# "If for every eigenvalue of matrix A - the algebraic multiplicity equals 1 so A is diagonalizable" True/False?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

I can't find the answer. I know that $A$ is diagonalizable  if and only if its minimal polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors , but I can't determine if it's true according to the given information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* If $F$ is a field and $A$ is a square matrix over $F$, then the followings are equivalent:

1. $A$ is diagonalizable over $F$
2. The minimal polynomial of $A$ has distinct zeros in $F$.

Now if $m(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$, then $m(x)$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $A$. In your case, what can you say about $m(x)$?

Comment: I know that the degree of m(x) is 1 (?) . But is it tells me that it's product of distinct linear factors? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @A-H. If the degree of $m(x)$ is 1, then you are in a prefect situation since $m(x)$ is a product of distinct linear factors. (Yes, linear polynomials considered as product of distinct linear factors!) But in general, the given condition does not necessarily imply that $m(x)$ is of degree 1. Rather, it implies that all the zeros of $m(x)$ are also distinct (otherwise the characteristic polynomial would also have a zero with multiplicity $\geq 2$).

Comment: Ok, so I understand the fact is true. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For arbitrary fields this is not well formulated. With $F=\Bbb R$, I would say that $X^3+X$ has distinct zeros (in fact just one) in$~F$, yet a real matrix with that minimal polynomial is not diagonalisable over$~F$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue (i.e. the dimension of the associated eigenspace) is always $\ge 1$ and $\le$ the algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: I know that, so the geometric multiplicity is also 1 , but i don't know that the characteristic polynomial is product of linear factors (not distinct necessarily) and it is required for determine it's diagonalizable. Or maybe can I get it from the givens?

Comment: @A-H A matrix is diagonalizable iff for each eigenvalue, the geometric and algebraic multiplicities are equal. So we are done

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this condition is not enough, it's required also that the characteristic polynomial is product of linear factors. Am I wrong ?

Comment: As Ahmed stated,equality of geometric and algebraic multiplicities is necessary and sufficient condition for matrix to be diagonalizable.
Notice the iff in his comment.